# ReactJs, how to wait for my function to return something

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an function call isAuthenticated that check the token validity like that :

```
isAuthenticated = async () => {

        const data = await request.call({
            url: `http://localhost:1337/utilisateurs/VerifyUserTok`,
            method: `post`,
            parameters : {
                authorization: `bearer ${sessionStorage.getItem(`token`)}`
            }
        });

        if (data.IsValide){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and in my protected route, if the previous function return false, I do not redirect the person. But 
in the protected.route.js file, the function go in the first return without waiting for my isAuthenticated function to return something :

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import auth from './auth.js'
import NavMenu from './NavMenu';

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    return (
        <Route 
            {...rest} 
            render = {props => {
                if(auth.isAuthenticated()){
                    return <div className="page-body">
                                <Route>
                                    <NavMenu/>
                                    <div className="right-body">
                                        <Component {...props}/>
                                    </div>
                                </Route>
                            </div>
                } else {
                    return <Redirect to={
                        {
                            pathname: "/",
                            state: {
                                from: props.location
                            }
                        }     
                    } />
                }

            }}
        />
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want some state that holds the information you're looking for, and you'll want to execute the auth lookup in an effect.

Of course, you might choose to have some way to display a loading indicator while the auth check is in flight, but you can figure out that mechanism as you need it.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import auth from './auth.js'
import NavMenu from './NavMenu';

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
    const [isAuthed, setIsAuthed] = useState(false);
    const [isLoaded, setIsLoaded] = useState(false);

    // Assuming you just want to check on initial render
    useEffect(() => {
      let mounted = true;
      const checkAuth = async () => {
        const authed = await auth.isAuthenticated();
        if (mounted) {
          setIsAuthed(authed);
          setIsLoaded(true);
        }
      checkAuth();
      return () => {
        mounted = false;
      }
    }, [])

    return !isLoaded ? "Loading..." : (
        <Route 
            {...rest} 
            render = {props => {
                if(isAuthed){
                    return <div className="page-body">
                                <Route>
                                    <NavMenu/>
                                    <div className="right-body">
                                        <Component {...props}/>
                                    </div>
                                </Route>
                            </div>
                } else {
                    return <Redirect to={
                        {
                            pathname: "/",
                            state: {
                                from: props.location
                            }
                        }     
                    } />
                }

            }}
        />
    );
}
```

Comment: I got this error with your solution : Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
    in ProtectedRoute (at App.js:13)

Comment: @William I added a cleanup function to the `useEffect` hook that should clear up that error

Comment: I tried, but its still not waiting for the function to return something

Comment: I think this issue is that it's redirecting before it gets a chance to do the async stuff. I'm going to add another stateful variable to indicate loading status

Comment: Alright, now no redirect can possibly happen until the loading completes

Answer (score 2):

You could handle three different state for your `isAuthenticated()` result. undefined, true, and false.

- undefined : your component will display a loader waiting for your API Call to end
- true/false: same behavior as you have.

Just store it in a variable and do something like that :

```
// ... Ommited code
if(isAuthed === undefined) return <Loader />;
return (
// ... Your code with true/false condition
```